# Geany keyboard issue

Tags: geany, geany-plugin

I am using Geany with  Windows 7 .
I seem to have messed up some settings 
When I press **double quote key** it seem to display some other key on the geany.

Attached is the screen shot of the issue.

Please guide on the same

Reinstalled geany but same issue persists[image]

Comment: in the comment to an answer you say what you did. You may want to post it as an answer. The guidelines encourage you to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I have exactly the same problem here! What have you done to solve this?

Comment: Uninstall, try removing the registry and reinstall the latest. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Menu "Tools" - Plugin Manager - Choose "Auto-close"

At the bottom of the window - the Preferences button

Uncheck the checkboxes "Double quotes" and "Single quotes"

Click the Apply and Ok button and everything will work as it should.